# CellFactory that calculates value in the background

Tags: javafx, tableview

I would like to calculate a table's cell content asynchronously in the background. I came up with the following solution:

```
public abstract class AsynchronousCellFactory<E, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<E, T>, TableCell<E, T>> {


    @Override
    public TableCell<E, T> call(final TableColumn<E, T> param) {
    final TableCell<E, T> cell = new TableCell<E, T>() {

        private Service<T> service;

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final T item, final boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (service != null) {
            service.cancel();
        }
        if (empty || this.getTableRow() == null || this.getTableRow().getItem() == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText("Calculating..");
            final E rowDataItem = (E) this.getTableRow().getItem();
            service = new Service<T>() {

            @Override
            protected Task<T> createTask() {
                return getTask(rowDataItem);
            }
            };
            service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            setText(e.getSource().getValue().toString());
            });
            service.setOnFailed(e -> {
            final Throwable t = e.getSource().getException();
            setText(t.getLocalizedMessage());
            });
            service.start();
        }
        }
    };

    return cell;
    }

    protected abstract Task<T> getTask(E rowDataItem);

}
```

I use this factory for almost all of my columns to calculate different values.
But this does not work very well.
I frequently see cell contents saying *Calculating*. When I double click on that cell, which triggers a repaint apparently, the correct value appears. 
Furthermore, even worse, I see sometimes that cell content is "switched" between columns: `stringA`, that should be in `columnA`, is in `comlumnB`, for example. Again, a double click on that cell fixes that.

I know that those factories are reused by the table columns to calculate cell content for different items, I assume the error is connected to that fact.

[image]

**EDIT:** When I move the `service` field to the `TableCell`, the *Calculating* error seems to be fixed, nevertheless, the *switched-values* problem persists.

Find a MWE [here](https://github.com/kerner1000/asynchronous-cellfactory). It is actually not a *working example*, since it does not reproduce the problem. I guess the cell factory is working OK, and I am doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: What does your implementation of `getService()` look like? If you are trying to share service instances between different cells, that won't work. Can you not create a [MCVE] for this?

Comment: I created a runnable example, but  it does not reproduce the problem. I guess I have a problem in my actual implementation of the task, which is somehow mixing up entities from the database. I guess the question is somehow invalid now..